# Stripe Subscription with Initial setup fee

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I'm building a relatively simple subscription based app using Stripe.

My only real hangup at the moment is that the subscription requires an initial setup fee, and I'm really having a hard time with it.

Example:
A new user signs-up for Subscription-A; Subscription-A has a monthly interval price of $10. Upon signing up the new user gets charged a one-time fee of $1 and $10 for subscription, then the following months gets charged only $10.

Currently my code is:

```
// Stripe New customer
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "email" => $customer_email,
    "source" => $token,
  ),
  array("stripe_account" => $connected_account)
  );

// Stripe Subscription
  $sub = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
    "customer" => $customer['id'],
    "items" => array(
      array(
        "plan" => $plan_id,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  array("stripe_account" => $connected_account)
  );
```

Any idea? thx

Comment: what version of stripe are you using? I don't recognise the `array("stripe_account" => $connected_account)` parameter

Comment: @Wee last stripe version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After [creating the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer), but before [creating the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription), [create an invoice item](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem) for the setup fee.

When you create the subscription, a first invoice will be immediately created, and this invoice will include all pending invoice items for the customer.

For more information about invoice items, see https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/invoices#adding-invoice-items.

Comment: thx it works but 1$ fee invoice is transfer to `$connected_account`, anyway to transfer it to principal company account?

Comment: @Rubyx just set `$connected_account` to the company account